# Neovim does not highlight syntax unless I'm logged in as root

Tags: neovim

My config file for Neovim under `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` looks like this

```
:set ignorecase
:set smartcase
:set nu

:let $VIMRUNTIME="/usr/share/nvim/runtime"
:let $VIM="/usr/share/nvim"
:let $NVIM="/usr/share/nvim"
```

I need to set up those variables, otherwise they default to `/home/.vimrc` which is not present (and shouldn't be).

When I enter Neovim and run `:syntax on` I get this message:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim:
line   42:
E216: No such group or event: filetypedetect BufRead
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I open the same file with `sudo nvim <file>` syntax highlighting works fine. I've checked those 3 environment variables in the `sudo` version and they have the exact same value as the config file - if I remove/rename the config file, those variables stay the same in the `sudo` version.

Is there a way for me to solve this syntax issue when not running Neovim as root?

Comment: Could you tell us which version of Vim you are using? What is the output of the `:version` command?

Comment: why are you setting the `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` variables? That should not be necessary

Comment: Nvim has the version `0.2.2` and Vim has the version `8.1`.

Comment: For some reason those two variables are set to `/home/.vimrc/` which doesn't exist. Do I need to make a folder in the `/home/` directory with that name?

Comment: The vim configuration for **root** is getting used when you go with `sudo` , while the vim configuration for your **user** is used without that. You should log in as root & verify that vim works the way you want it , then copy that configuration over to your user home directory.

Comment: I'm not sure @Prem's solution is correct (though diagnosis, maybe). I would (1) triple-check your installation, since setting those env vars is odd and (2) check permissions on your config files.

Comment: And (3) never use `sudo vim` :) Prefer `sudoedit`/`sudo -e` when possible

Comment: I did think about root Permissions , though there were too many Directory & file Items + variations to list out , in that Comment Box , @D.BenKnoble , thus I suggested copying over the working configuration , which may not be "optimal" , but is it wrong ?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I've looked for `/home/.vimrc` within all my files in the system. For some reason my `bashrc` was setting those variables to the wrong initial value which kind of messed up the whole system for me. I initially thought there was some config file that root was using, but it turns out root was pretty empty and was using default values.

Comment: Nice to see that you got it resolved , though the resolution is still the same "copy over the working configuration from root" , where "the working configuration" is actually mostly "Empty" to make vim use the Default values.